# Making inputs and selects fill remaining width

Tags: html, css, forms

I am trying to setup a form such that:

- All inputs will be horizontally aligned, even when they have no label.
- Inputs will be vertically aligned within their row for when the label wraps.
- The inputs will stretch to fill the remaining space (or squished)
- The submit button will fill an entire row.

I have achieved the first and fourth requirements but I am having trouble with making the inputs fill the row and be vertically aligned.

Here's my progress so far:
http://jsbin.com/kozozabo/3/edit?html,css,output

The LESS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#narrow-form {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;

  padding-right: 0.5em;
}

#wide-form {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;

  margin-left: 300px;
}

.row {
  @label-width: 100px;

  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;

  label {    
    width: @label-width;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .no-label {
    margin-left: @label-width; 
  }

  input, select {
    /* Trying to make these aligned to the right of 
     * their respective labels filling any remaining   
     * width.
     */
    display: inline-block;
  }

  button {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

I tried giving the inputs absolute positioning with a left margin of the same width of the label but that didn't work.

Comment: You could make a container around them and make the inputs 100%?

Comment: you could use a table.

Comment: I would prefer not to have to change the DOM as this form is being built by javascript. I have managed to get a version using `display` and `table*` attributes but am not having trouble with getting label-less inputs being aligned. http://jsbin.com/kozozabo/5/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have come up with a solution that I am happy with. It does involve some table abuse unfortunately.

I have only tested this in Chromium.

http://jsbin.com/kozozabo/5/edit?output

I set the form to `display: table`, each `.row` to `display: table-row` and the labels, inputs, selects and buttons to `display: table-cell`.

This made everything line up and fill all available space.

I then added two new classes intended to be affixes to the `.row` class, this is where the real table abuse begins.

`.no-label` - With the intent of "skipping" the first psuedo-cell. To accomplish this I defined it as such:

```
.no-label:before {
  content: "";
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Essentially inserting a hidden cell, forcing the subsequent inputs to be in the second column.

`.full-width` - With the intent of making it's contents the full width of the "table". To accomplish this I defined it as such:

```
.full-width {
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: bottom;
}
```

A table caption spans the entire width of the table. I know I am only going to do this to the button so I forced it to be at the bottom with `caption-side`.

It would have been better to just define the DOM as a table but I didn't want to reprogram the javascript that was setting up this form. I always wouldn't get to of played with css, all be it in a menacing manner.